# Tkinter TypeError with a function callback and Input Update issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter GUI programming, and I am hoping to run a shell script from a Tkinter button.  I'm running into a few errors.  What I hope to do is pass two inputs into a bash shell script, but when I press the 'Run' button, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/antelope/python2.7.8/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: call() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

The second issue is that the inputs into the bash script do not change when I edit the inputs.  Could this be an issue with the .get() command?  Thanks.
The Code currently looks like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os; import obspy
class MyGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master = Frame(root)
        master.pack(side='top')
    ##### Input One
        self.one_txt = Label(master, text='Input One')
        self.one_txt.pack(side='top')
        self.one = StringVar()
        self.one.set('1349860')
        self.one_entry = Entry(master, width=10, textvariable=self.one, justify=CENTER, relief=RAISED, background='yellow',font=("bold") );
        self.one_entry.pack(side='top')
    ##### Input Two
        self.two_text = Label(master,text='two')
        self.two_text.pack(side='top')
        self.two = StringVar()
        self.two.set('abcde')
        self.two_entry = Entry(master, width=10, textvariable=self.two, justify=CENTER, relief=RAISED, font=("bold"));
        self.two_entry.pack(side='top') 
  ## Define a function for the button callback
        self.one4bash = self.one.get(); self.two4bash = self.two.get()
        def script4bash(self):
            os.system("bash script1.sh %s %s" % (self.one4bash, self.two4bash))
        self.runBash = Button(master, text='Run', command=self.one4bash)
        self.runBash.pack(side='top')
root = Tk()
root.title("Event Discrimination Window")
mygui = MyGui(root)
root.geometry("500x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: two question with same error ! Need learn class construction. `root = Tk()` before `def __init__(self, master):` programming language not `fortune teller tools`

Comment: def script4bash(self): is indented one level too many.  It is under " __init__" not the class.

Comment: Also, "command=" executes a function, and you have it trying to execute the result that was returned earlier by the get() function, see "command=" at  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm